# Resolving resource using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I face such problem: I have abstract state:

```
    $stateProvider.state('bookings.clients', {
        url:"/clients",
        abstract:true,
        views:{
            "@":{
                templateUrl:"/Static/CrmPages/CrmMainPage.html",
                controller:"CrmMainPageController",

            }
        },
        resolve: {
            clientsData:function(clientsDataService) {
                return clientsDataService.loadData('ihor.korotenko@n-cube.co.uk');
            },
            clientsGroupsData: function (userGroupsService) {
                //return "some";
                return userGroupsService.api.query(function (data) {
                    userGroupsService.data = data;
                }).$promise;
            }

        }


});
```

As you can see there are two resolve objects.
Than, I inject this objects to controller in child state:

```
angular.module("crmModule")
.controller("mainPageController", ['clientsGroupsData', 'clientsData', "$scope", "$rootScope", "$translate", 'clients', 'cultureProvider', '$state', function (clientsGroupsData, clientsData, $scope, $rootScope, $translate, clients, cultureProvider, $state)
```

My resource provider:

```
angular.module("crmModule")
.service("userGroupsService", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
var self = this;
self.data = [];
return {
    api: $resource("/api/groupsapi/getallgroups"),
    data: self.data
}
```

}])
 Child state:

```
    $stateProvider.state('bookings.clients.overview', {
    url:"/overview",
    views:{
        "crm.main":{
            templateUrl: "/Static/CrmPages/main-page.html",
            controller:"mainPageController"
        }
    },

});
```

The problem is following: when controller instantiates I see that injected object is not empty and resolved(It`s ok), but after that I get an exception

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: clientsGroupsDataProvider <- clientsGroupsData <- mainPageController
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the reason of this error, it occurs because I attach controller in html via `ng-controller` directive, and of course, ui-router can`t inject dependency because it doesnt intantiate controller.